# Opening a link to a new tab, and then opening another link onto that same tab that just opened

Tags: html, css

So I already know how to open a link into a new tab by using the `target=_blank`. 
My question is how do you open a second link onto that same tab instead of opening another new tab making three instead of two tabs?

Example:

```
<a href="allProducts.html" target=_blank>Products</a>
```

When clicked, should open a new tab.

```
<a href="allArtists.html" target=_blank>Artists</a>
```

When this is clicked, should open onto the previous new tab and not open another new tab.

So you should have the initial page, then click on `allProducts` to get that page on a new tab, and then click `allArtists` to open onto the `allProducts` tab to replace it instead of opening a third tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `<a>`s a common `target` attribute, one other than `_blank`, for example:

```
<a href="allProducts.html" target="sidewindow">Products</a>
<a href="allArtists.html" target="sidewindow">Artists</a>
```

Cannot embed due to stack snippet sandboxing, but you can see it in action here:

https://jsfiddle.net/kbqp6dwa/

Comment: Thanks! I tested it out and totally works the way you suggested. I am still learning and appreciate the help!

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)